# Impractical Routine?

Tags: workout-routines, strength-training

So I've been trying to get into working out for the past year, but I'm a high school kid who doesn't have the time (or skill sadly) for sports and a gym membership just isn't an option. I try to keep in shape by doing this routine but the more I think about it, the less practical it seems. What I do is 46 pushups (I'm not sure why I stop at 46 instead of 45 but I do), 18 curls with a 15 lb dumbbell on each arm, some forearm exercises (3 types and 25 each arm but it's not very intense), 15-17 squats with two 15 lb weights in hand, and then a plank anywhere from 1min30 to 2min. Then I try doing this 3 times more, so 4 in total, but I stretch it out over like 3-5 hours depending on how tiring my day was. I've been struggling more and more with keeping this up, its hard to force myself and often I'll only do 2 or 3 sets a day. Should I try to do it all at once or maybe 2 sets, then rest for a little and then the other two? I'm not very satisfied with my current situation and haven't seen much improvement in a while (maybe I'm getting softer). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: "3-5 hours" "'I'm a high school kid who doesn't have the time". A decent "routine" will take you something between 45 and 90 minutes to complete. I don't have the time to write an answer (I have do my 60 minutes now), but consider that when you argue with not enough time. You also lack something called progressive overload (google) which (my guess) is why you don't see any improvements anymore. Another common reason would be you not eating enough or the wrong stuff